# Calculating Churn Rate for per model ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, feature-extraction

I want to divide the **Churn Flag** column into **Y** and **N** columns to calculate the **Churn rate** per model id easily. There are total 365 unique model id. So i want to keep only the model with **churn rate** grater than 80%  because it's not easy to do it manually so i want to do it via programme. But to do it first I have to divide the churn flag as **Y** and **N**.

Sample of the dataframe:-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: This will keep models with churn rate > 80%

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='model id', columns='churn flag', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0).reset_index()
df.columns=['model id', 'N', 'Y']
df['churn rate'] = df['Y'] / (df['N'] + df['Y'])
df = df[df['churn rate']>0.8]
```

Comment: code has a problem it's interchange the value if Y and N like model id 102 has N =10 and Y=2 but it calculating as Y=10 and N=2

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Model Id': ['102', '102', '1094', '2017p','225','225','250U','3000'], 'churn flag': ['N','Y','Y','N','N','Y','N','N'], 'count':[10,2,1,12,37,1,60,6]})

dict(iter(df.groupby('churn flag')))
```

This will give you

```
{'N':   Model Id churn flag  count
 0      102          N     10
 3    2017p          N     12
 4      225          N     37
 6     250U          N     60
 7     3000          N      6,
 'Y':   Model Id churn flag  count
 1      102          Y      2
 2     1094          Y      1
 5      225          Y      1}
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I want only one dataframe and Y and N per model not 102 times only one time 102 with respect to that two column Y and N